# How to authenticate in angular using firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase

How to auth using provider in angular fire auth?

I'm trying to authenticate users using auth providers.

this is what all the tutorials out there suggests,
to create a provider instance using `import { auth } from 'firebase/app';`

But I get the error:
`'"firebase/app"' has no exported member 'auth'`

Following is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
  ) { }

  // Sign in with Facebook
  FacebookAuth() {
    return this.AuthLogin(new auth.FacebookAuthProvider());
  }  

  // Auth logic to run auth providers
  AuthLogin(provider) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
        console.log('You have been successfully logged in!')
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
  }

}
```

But when I try to import this  `import { auth } from 'firebase/app';`, the compiler throws error saying that the module has no exported member called auth. May I know how can I work it out?

**Or is there a new method for this, other than using any third party libraries like `angularx-social-login` or `ngx-auth-firebaseui`**

Comment: which version do u use? It is working with  "@angular/fire": "6.0.0", "firebase": "7.14.3",

Comment: Latest version of firebase